# Итеративное удаление значений из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как удалять значения из списка [1, 2, 3], чтобы на выходе получилось [2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2]. Если делать это в цикле вот так

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = []
for i in  my_list:
    new_list.append(my_list.remove(i))
```

то по очереди убираются все значения из списка, а это не то что нам нужно.

Comment: Не могу понять вопрос. Уточните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить сочетание из `my_list` по 2, то можно воспользоваться [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

res = list(combinations(my_list, 2))
```

результат:

```
In [489]: print(res)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

если нужен строго список **списков**:

```
res = list(map(list, combinations(my_list, 2)))
```

результат:

```
In [491]: res
Out[491]: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

---

Сочетание с повторениями:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

In [493]: list(combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 2))
Out[493]: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Лучше использовать всё же позиции элементов для их исключения, а не удалять сами элементы:

```
new_list = [[x for j,x in enumerate(my_list) if i != j] for i in range(len(my_list))]
print(new_list)
```

Вам в любом случае придётся как-то копировать список, а не "резать по живому". Если добавить копирование к вашему коду, то будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    tmp_list = my_list.copy()
    tmp_list.remove(i)
    new_list.append(tmp_list)
print(new_list)
```

Тут ещё надо помнить, что `remove` удаляет элемент и ничего не возвращет.

UPD: При большой длине входного списка оптимальнее использовать второй вариант из-за его линейной сложности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.